# How to get subset of list in neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, subset

I wonder how to get a subset of a list in Cypher?

Lets assume the following Cypher query:

```
WITH ['a','b','c'] AS set1,  ['b'] AS set2
RETURN set1, set2
```

I want to get as a `RETURN` result of `set3` that is a subset of `set1` containing only the values `['a','c']`.
So the content of `set2` (the `['b']` value in this sample) is filtered out.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks,
Koen

Answer (score 1):

Using just Cypher, you can use a filter operation on the list, ensuring that the only values you keep are those that are not in the second list:

```
WITH ['a','b','c'] AS set1,  ['b'] AS set2
RETURN [item in set1 WHERE NOT item in set2] as set3
```

Though if you have the [APOC Procedures plugin](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), you can use one of the collection functions to perform list subtraction:

```
WITH ['a','b','c'] AS set1,  ['b'] AS set2
RETURN apoc.coll.subtract(set1, set2) as set3
```

Comment: Hi thanks ! Yes i am using apoc and I also found the "apoc.coll.disjunction(set1, set2)" function that seems to also work fine in the sample as provided. However when i embed both apoc based queries in my bigger cypher query they give me a java.nullpointer exception while the pure cypher query works fine

Comment: which might be due to the fact that one of the 2 sets might be "null".. anyways .. i can proceed .. thanks a lot